# Does calling dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue()) on main thread cause app to "hang"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

```
// Method called when a button is clicked

- (void)handleClickEvent {
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         [self backgroundProcessing];
      });
      // Some code to update the UI of the view
      ....
      [self updateUI];
      ....
}
```

1) handleClickEvent is called on the main thread when a button on the view is pressed.

2) I  used dispatch_sync() because the following code that updates the UI of the view cannot be done until a variable in the backgroundProcessing method is calculated.

3) I used dispatch_get_global_queue in order to get the backgroundProcessing off the main thread. (following the rule: generally put background processing off main thread and generally put code that affect the UI on the main thread).

My question is: Does the backgroundProcessing method "hang" the main thread until it is complete since I am using dispatch_sync?

**EDIT:**
Based on the answer below i have implemented this solution:

```
- (void)handleClickEvent {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         [self backgroundProcessing];
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateUI];
         });
      });
}
```

solution from this link: [Completion Callbaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, dispatch_sync will block until the task is complete. Use dispatch_async and when the job is complete have it post a block back to the main queue to update the view.

Comment: Ok so it will block the main thread even though it was dispatched on the global queue. I got you. Ok thanks much. I have edit the question above to show the answer i implemented.

Comment: I think the key line from the documentation on dispatch_sync() you may have missed was: "As an optimization, dispatch_sync() invokes the block on the current thread when possible." To achieve the effect you were looking for, you should have async dispatched the work and then async dispatched the UI update on the main queue when the work was done.  This is a common pattern.